# fails to set up nginx and php with odd error that nginx can't recognize php

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, app-config, config

I am setting up Nginx to use with Laravel
I created the default project with laravel and installed epel nginx already,
But when I run the site e.g `http://localhost/mysite`
the browser asks me to download the index.php file

I only added in default nginx config (default.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/)
the line

```
server
{
root /var/www/html/mysite/public;
}
```

and I leave nginx.conf (in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) untouched.

Comment: Did you install PHP? Nginx is a webserver which means it returns data. It does not calculate data so you will need to install the PHP extension/plugin for Nginx.

Comment: I think I installed all modules, Nginx just doesn't recognize PHP

Answer (score 0):

This is a good step-by-step article on how to get Laravel, Nginx, and PHP working on an Ubuntu server (you can probably adapt settings if you want another linux distro):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

You are missing the PHP install and the hooks to make Nginx send the processing to the PHP engine.